# Can I determine what was clicked using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once again I've inherited someone else's system which is a bit of a mess. I'm currently working with an old ASP.NET (VB) webforms app that spits JavaScript onto the client via the server - not nice! I'm also limited on what I can edit in regards to the application.

I have a scenario where I have a function that does a simple exercise but would also need to know what item was clicked to executed the function, as the function can be executed from a number of places within the system...

Say I had a function like so...

```
 function updateMyDiv() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div13').show();
 }
```

how could I get the ID (for example) of the HTML element that was clicked to execute this?

Something like:

```
function updateMyDiv() {

    alert(htmlelement.id) // need to raise the ID of what was clicked, 

    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div13').show();
}
```

I can expand on this if neccessary, do I need to pass `this` as an arguement?

Comment: Where is your `.click` event handler? Wherever it is, the variable `this` inside of it will be the element clicked upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your click events with jQuery and then reference $(this)

```
$('.myDivClass').live('click', function () {
    updateMyDiv(this);
});

var updateMyDiv = function (that) {
   alert(that.id);

   // save the world
};
```

Comment: This suited mmy needs best, although the event handler was the problem due to the complexity of the system I was trying to ammend. Thanks everyone for their answers and help!

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword references the element that fired the event. Either:

```
<element onClick="doSomething(this);">
```

or

```
element.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass "`this`", it is assigned automatically. You can do something like this:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the function as the elements event handler is one way,

```
$(htmlelement).click(updateMyDiv);
```

If you are working with an already generated event, you can call `getElementByPoint` and pass in the events x,y coords to get the element the mouse was hovering over.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.something').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass it the `event.target` variable.

```
$("element").click(function(event) {
    updateMyDiv($(event.target));
});

function updateMyDiv(target) {
    alert(target.prop("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `.click` event handler? Wherever it is, the variable `this` inside of it will be the element clicked upon.

If you have an `onclick` attribute firing your function, change it to

```
<tag attribute="value" onclick="updateMyDiv(this)">
```

and change the JavaScript to

```
function updateMyDiv(obj) {
    alert(obj.getAttribute('id')) // need to raise the ID of what was clicked, 

    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div13').show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the `.attr('id')` method and specify the id which will return what you need.